# Getting and setting user-agent in uiwebview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am trying to display an image from a url into my UIWebview but the image size is too small to be displayed without making it blurred by stretching it..Since i cannot auto-resize the image(as it gets blurred) i was thinking of getting and setting user-agent value for iphone...But i m not able to find much relevant info about it and i am also not sure if it'll work or not?? anybody having any idea how it can be accomplished??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement a `UIWebViewDelegate` class, you can fetch the Request with `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` – at this point you should be able to manipulate the Request, something like

```
[request setValue:@"your custom useragent" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Answer (score 0):

To **get** the User-Agent, you can try using javascript [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4846373/119114) or as in the answer from [@cem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109156/119114), you can implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and then *read* the header field from the request object passed to your `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
[request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

For **setting**, however, the `UIWebViewDelegate` method did not work for me with iOS 5.  Maybe it did in the past.

What worked for me was actually to define an application-wide user default for the `UserAgent` key (that's not a typo ... there's no hyphen between the words *User* and *Agent*).

In my app delegate, I used an initializer, to get this value set before any `UIWebViews` or `NSURLRequests` were created:

```
+ (void) initialize {
    // TODO: put in whatever custom user agent you want here:
    NSString* userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19";

    NSDictionary* initDefaults = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  userAgent, @"UserAgent",
                                  nil];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:initDefaults];  
}
```

Note: if you're not using ARC, remember to release `initDefaults` in the snippet above.