# Getting HTTP headers with xcode

Tags: xcode, http, header, user-agent, nsurlrequest

I am trying to get the user agent but when I try and read it, it comes out (null)

```
NSLog(@"user agent = %@", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);
```

request is an NSURLRequest. So I tried to get the http headers and I don't think there are any. When I use

```
NSLog(@"http headers = %d", [[req allHTTPHeaderFields] fileSize]);
```

it prints out zero.  req is an NSMutableURLRequest. Does anyone know why this is happening.

This is the method that I am using:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView )webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType { 
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = (NSMutableURLRequest *)request; 
    NSString *versionString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString)kCFBundleVersionKey];
NSLog(@"http headers = %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
NSLog(@"http headers = %d", [[req allHTTPHeaderFields] fileSize]);
[req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myApp/%@ %@", versionString, [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    NSLog(@"user agent = %@", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);}
```

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"http headers = %d", [[req allHTTPHeaderFields] count]);` print?

Comment: you're not getting any headers back.  you'll need to post more of your code for us to diagnose further.

Comment: This is the method that I am using.

Comment: `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
 
 NSMutableURLRequest *req = (NSMutableURLRequest *)request;
 NSString *versionString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];

Comment: `NSLog(@"http headers = %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
 NSLog(@"http headers = %d", [[req allHTTPHeaderFields] fileSize]); 
  
 [req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myApp%@ %@", versionString, [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    NSLog(@"user agent = %@", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);

}`

Comment: I started editing your post to add the method but realized it was incomplete.  Can you edit your post and add the rest of the method?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString* secretAgent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
    NSLog(@"navigator.userAgent = %@", secretAgent);

    NSDictionary* headers = [request allHTTPHeaderFields];
    NSLog(@"headers: %@",headers);

    NSString* ua = [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    NSLog(@"User-Agent = %@", ua);
}
```

I don't know why you're looking at `filesize` when you can just look at the headers themselves.

Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19184414/1431728

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any headers in your request object because you haven't added any.  If you want to specify the `User-Agent` header, you need to add it yourself, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1532206/3009).

Comment: I tried that link and I got the same problem. The user agent is still (null) before I change it. ` NSLog(@"user agent = %@", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);` So when I add stuff to it and then run the NSLog again I get something that looks like `myApp/1.0 (null)`

Comment: in the code above, you are setting the User-Agent to the current value of User-Agent - which is null.  You have to supply your own value.

Comment: Shouldn't there already be a user-agent. Something like Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1