# How to get the user agent on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way on iOS to get the user agent of the device? I don't want to hard code it since I need the user agent for all devices and I need to append the user agent to a URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A simpler way to ascertain the user agent in iOS is to get it directly from a `UIWebView` using the accepted answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297733/how-to-get-uiwebview-user-agent). To quote that answer:

> The solution was to create a UIWebView and then just use javascript to pull out the user agent.
>
> ```
> UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
> NSString* secretAgent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
> ```

Comment: No need to make a web request and wait for it's materialisation to get http header. For me this is the answer! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. An important note is that, you need to call this in the main thread. Thus in some circumstances, you might need to wrap your answer's code inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });

Comment: UIWebview is no more

Comment: This is not entirely accurate, the user agent used for `URLSession` might be different than the user agent used for a `UIWebView`.

Comment: `UIWebView` is deprecated so this solution should no longer be used :)

Answer (score 14):

Mobile application in every request must send his `User-Agent` header with build version and device information

[User agent configuration info](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-145)

So, user agent should be like:

`User-Agent: <AppName>/version (<system-information>) <platform> (<platform-details>) <extensions>`

For iOS:

`User-Agent: <AppName/<version> (<iDevice platform>; <Apple model identifier>; iOS/<OS version>) CFNetwork/<version> Darwin/<version>`

How to get each of the components?

1. Headers Key - u can hardcode or use [some constant values](https://gist.github.com/kirillgorbushko/878540ca1e483a16a0c6ed5eb4082d90)
2. AppName and version - [grab from `Info.plist`](https://gist.github.com/kirillgorbushko/bc5b4b3574101b00e56c091c31cdd683)

   ```
    let infoPlist = try? PListFile<InfoPlist>()
    let appName = infoPlist.data.bundleName
    let version = infoPlist.data.versionNumber
    let build = infoPlist.data.buildNumber
   ```
3. Info about Device

`modelName` - you can obtain like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197770/2012219)

```
    let modelName = UIDevice.current.modelName
```

other components:

```
    let platform = UIDevice.current.systemName
    let operationSystemVersion = ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersionString
```

4. CFNetwork version

   ```
    static var cfNetworkVersion: String? {
      guard
        let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.apple.CFNetwork"),
         let versionAny = bundle.infoDictionary?[kCFBundleVersionKey as String],
         let version = versionAny as? String
          else { return nil }
      return version
    }
   ```

[from here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124183)

5. Darwin Version

   ```
     var systemInfo = utsname()
     uname(&systemInfo)
     let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.release)
     let darvinVersionString = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
       guard let value = element.value as? Int8,
         value != 0 else {
           return identifier
       }

       return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
     }
   ```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60503116/2012219)

Result:

> MyApp/1.8.199 (iOS; iPhone XS; Version 13.3 (Build 17C45)) CFNetwork/1121.2.1 Darvin/19.3.0

Answer (score 6):

You don’t actually need to make the request in order to get the user-agent. Just return NO from the following delegate method and retain the user-Agent header:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

It might look something like this:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{  
     userAgent = [[request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"] copy]; 
     NSLog(@"user-agent: %@", userAgent);

     _webView.delegate = nil; 
     [_webView release]; 

     return NO; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**(iOS 8.0, *)**

Since UIWebView is deprecated in iOS 12, you should use WKWebView instead.

Since WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript(_:) result is now async, this implementation solve a common requirement to have userAgent available in your own REST api call.

```
import WebKit

class UAString {

    static var userAgent : String = ""

    @discardableResult init(view parent: UIView) {

        if UAString.userAgent.isEmpty {

            let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())

            webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            parent.addSubview(webView)

            webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { result, _ in
                UAString.userAgent = result as? String ?? ""
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now last part you can implement this class in your initial view controller as follow:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    UAString(view: self.view)
}
```

then you can access the attribute as `UAString.userAgent`

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C

```
WKWebView *webView = [WKWebView new];
res = [webView valueForKey:@"userAgent"];
```

Swift

```
let ua = WKWebView().value(forKey: "userAgent")
```

Dont forget to import WebKit

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.x, 4.x, 5.x, & above**

As sometime traditional UIWebView get's memory leaked so instead use always WKWebView (far better from UIWebView)

```
import WebKit

var webViewForUserAgent: WKWebView?
```

and get userAgent by calling below function & you can also set it to your other variable

```
func getUserAgent() {

    webViewForUserAgent = WKWebView() // must initialize

    webViewForUserAgent?.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { (result, error) in

        //
        if error != nil {
            print("Error occured to get userAgent")
            return
        }

        //
        if let unwrappedUserAgent = result as? String {
            print("userAgent: \(unwrappedUserAgent)")
        } else {
            print("Failed to get userAgent")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That won't compile because WKWebView() requires arguments.

Comment: Please share your code snippet, make sure you declare your webView as an optional

Answer (score -1):

A simpler way to ascertain the user agent in iOS is to get it directly from a UIWebView using the accepted answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297733/how-to-get-uiwebview-user-agent).But this way has two disadvantages:
1、UIWebView's first allocation may take too much time in initializing webview context.
2、the code must be executed in main thread. This may stuck main thread.
If you know the tricks of how to use private methods while avoiding the refusal of App Store Review.
You can try the following code:

```
    #define CALL_PRIVATE_INSTANCEMETHOD(x,sel,q)\
    {\
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@#sel]);\
    if ([x respondsToSelector:selector]) {\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic push")\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Warc-performSelector-leaks\"")\
    q=[x performSelector:selector];\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")\
    }\
    }\

    #define CALL_PRIVATE_CLASSMETHOD_ONEPARAM(x,sel,p,q)\
    {\
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%@:",@#sel]);\
    if ([x respondsToSelector:selector]) {\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic push")\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Warc-performSelector-leaks\"")\
    q=[x performSelector:selector withObject:p];\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")\
    }\
    }\

    + (NSString *)standardUserAgent{
        NSString *buildVersion = nil;
        CALL_PRIVATE_INSTANCEMETHOD([UIDevice currentDevice], buildVersion,buildVersion);

        Class webViewCls = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"Web",@"View"]);
        NSString *standardUA = nil;
        NSString *versions = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mobile/%@",buildVersion];
        CALL_PRIVATE_CLASSMETHOD_ONEPARAM(webViewCls, standardUserAgentWithApplicationName,versions,standardUA);    
        return standardUA;
    }
```