# Get iOS Device Default System User-Agent For HTTP Requests

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm communicating with an API that requires I use a particular user-agent string. The format for this is basically `User-Agent: IOS_USER_AGENT API_CUSTOM_AGENT`

Upon [investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8579019/1652402) I discovered that people would use `UIWebView` and apply a javascript function to extract the system user agent string. Now that `UIWebView` is deprecated, its replacement `WKWebView` offers an asynchronous means of calculating the user agent (not ideal for my purposes).

Is there any way to extract some form of the iOS user agent string without needing to randomly create some off-screen web view. Especially with `SFSafariViewController` I don't think its entirely impossible that these web views become deprecated in future.

I know that Apps like WhatsApp and Facebook use the system User-Agent [see here](https://mobiforge.com/research-analysis/webviews-and-user-agent-strings). The question is, what is the most reliable way of achieving this without involving web view trickery?