# Cocoa: Get Darwin version at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, darwin

How can I get the darwin version at runtime?
I know that I can get the macOS or iOS version using `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion]`, but I want the Darwin version.

There [are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11697362/2513803) [tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)#Release_history) on the internet linking macOS and iOS releases to a darwin version, but i want to implement this future-proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `uname()` POSIX/BSD library function. You declare a variable of type `struct utsname` and pass in its address. The `release` field of the struct will contain a C string with the Darwin version number, such as "16.3.0". If you want the individual components as integers, you'll have to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

adding code to @Ken Thomases response

```
  var systemInfo = utsname()
  uname(&systemInfo)
  let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.release)
  let darvinVersionString = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
    guard let value = element.value as? Int8,
      value != 0 else {
        return identifier
    }

    return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
  }
```

Sample response:

> 19.3.0

[image]

And [here a list of available versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system))