# Get the default app user agent for an iOS app

Tags: ios, user-agent, nsurlrequest

Many people have answered how to get the user-agent from a WebView, but I need the default user-agent that is normally sent in the http headers of an NSURLRequest.  What is the best way to get that one?

Comment: NSURLRequest has a property called `allHTTPHeaderFields` that returns a dictionary.  I don't know which key matches what you're looking for but, if you print the structure, you should be able to find it.

Comment: @PhillipMills That field appears to be empty unless you start the NSURLRequest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the user agent on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579019/how-to-get-the-user-agent-on-ios)